# JS commonjs exporting a function shows up as undefined

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I define a function in app.js like so:

```js
const sendNotif = (userIds, type, content) => {...}
exports.sendNotif = sendNotif;
```

And I import it in service.controller.js like so:

```js
const { sendNotif } = require("../app");
sendNotif(...)
```

When I hover over it in vscode I can see the function definition, however, when I run the code I get that sendNotif is not a function, when I log its type using typeof, I get undefined.

EDIT: I'm using nodejs without any bundlers or compilers, I'm also exporting an HTTP server in app.js by doing exports.http = htpp, and then I import that in index.js and use it, then it works fine. I'm able to import things from app.js everywhere else except in this file, I can't import anything.

UPDATE:
I tried do so:

```js
const app = require("../app");
console.log(app);
```

and I get an empty object

UPDATE: I'm able to import the function from apps within the same level, same directory, but not form files that are a level deeper, (ex ./ vs ../)

ANOTHER UPDATE: I updated my node version to 15.6 from 12.4 and now I get this output in the console:

```
(node:17052) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:17052) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'constructor' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:17052) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:17052) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

Comment: Have you tried with `module.exports.sendNotif` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that

Comment: @svoruganti try `module.exports={ sendNotif }`

Comment: @NileshPatel I tried that as well

Comment: @svoruganti I think you need to provide us more information. Are you using `node`? `webpack` or any other module bundler?

Comment: @svoruganti Thanks for the updated question. What happens if you `require("../app")` and then `console.log` it like this? `console.log(require("../app"))`.

Comment: @marco-a I get an empty object, {}

Comment: UPDATE: I'm able to import the function from apps within the same level, same directory, but not form files that are a level deeper, (ex ./ vs ../)